# mysql consistent read: transaction consistent snapshot

Tags: mysql, transactions, snapshot

I've got a database with several InnoDB tables I want to read from and then dump data to a XML format. Such XML would represent an object with all its related objects.

I wouldn't like any INSERT to be executed in the middle of my read process (SELECT, SELECT, bad INSERT, SELECT, ...) since this would cause data inconsistency. Which type of transactions should I use? I can't clearly see the difference between `START TRANSACTION` and `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: `LOCK TABLES` should work for you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't like to disable any writers to insert new records into the table (if it's possible).

Comment: well, you wont get a jack of all trades device here. Either those inserts/modifies will have to wait or you need to remember timestamps and remove any change during your dump on the files. But this isnt worth the effort imho. Anyway this is how dump does it anyway `NOTE: By default, all tables involved will be LOCK READ during mysqldump`

Comment: If there is a WRITE lock on a table and another client will want to insert a new row, he'll get an error. Is there any nice way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an excellent case for INNODB's transactional snapshot. You are right that the difference between WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT is  of minor importance - it only controls if the snapshot is taken at start transaction or if it is taken at first read.

What is important is that you must be executing in REPEATABLE_READ isolation level. This is the default level.

The other programs may insert or update as many records as they like, you will still get the version from your snapshot.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

Comment: well, seems like this is what I wanted to know... 1 year ago ;)